# Excel - How to consider Holidays and decrease the age count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Opened Date and Resolved date but in between opened and resolved date there is a holiday (Consider July 4th). I need to reduce "1" count from the age if the holiday falls in between Opened and Resolved Date. Below picture is the sample data...

Also if there are multiple holidays in between the opened and resolved date, the age should be decreased by "2"

[image]

Comment: You want [`NETWORKDAYS.INTL`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28)

Comment: what about weekends?

Comment: Do two networking days.  One with the holiday column included and one without.  Take the difference between them and you will have the number of holidays.

Comment: Is your date format MM-DD-YYYY?  IF so, your second holiday date is outside your open and resolve dates and will have no bearing.  How did you come to your values of D2 = 1 and D3 = 4

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Holidays are in G2..K2..

1. Put this formula in F2, it will count the number of Holidays > A2 and < B2

   =COUNTIFS(G2:K2,">"&A2,G2:K2,"<"&B2)
2. Put this formula in C2 to pick up the value in F2

   =B2-(A2+F2)

[Excel COUNTIFS Function](https:////https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function)

Enjoy...

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... but let me rephrase the question... i dont want the difference between opened and closed date.... If a holiday falls in between opened date and closed date, then i just want to do Age -1... If two holidays falls in between opened and closed date then i want to do is Age -2.... All my holiday list will be in single column (Assume only G column)

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mention in comment you can use `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()` function to indicate weekends in your country. If it is `Saturday-Sunday` then can use `NETWORKDAYS()` function. Try below-

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2,$G$2)
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,$G$2)
```

[image]

Comment: Harun, thank you so much for the reply... but let me rephrase the question... i dont want the difference between opened and closed date.... If a holiday falls in between opened date and closed date, then i just want to do Age -1... If two holidays falls in between opened and closed date then i want to do is Age -2

Comment: Here Age column is something that which already excludes saturday and Sunday...

Comment: Do you use any formula to age column? If used then try `=YourFormula - COUNTA(G2:K2)`.

Comment: No Harun... Age column is a raw data.... I want to do age calculation based on Holiday.... Column A,B,C in the give picture are raw data. So if Holiday is in between Opened Data and Closed Date, then in D column i just want to Age -1

Comment: @KannanPrince Understood. Use this formula `=C2-COUNTIFS(A2,"<="&G2,B2,">="&$G$2)`.

Comment: Working good Harun... what if I have all the holiday list in the G Column??

Comment: @KannanPrince Then use `=C2-COUNTIFS(G:G,">="&A2,G:G,"<="&B2)` If it solves your issue then tick marj the answer.